# how to get functionName from a javascriptCode which is in string format

Tags: javascript

this is my code

```
var javascriptCode="function adding(a,b){ return a+b}"
```

and i want to pick functionName `adding` from that string how to do that?

i have tried by finding its index as

```
var indexStart=javascriptCode.indexOf("function ");
var indexEnd=javascriptCode.indexOf("(");
var res = javascriptCode.substring(indexStart, indexEnd);
```

but i am getting the output as 
`function adding`, is their any other way to do this

Comment: Side note: most likely there are much better approaches to achieve your actual goal. Frequently evaluating script from string is sign of security issue. If you really have to do that - consider finding complete JavaScript parser instead of trying to parse string as correct script yourself.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov actually i am using ui-ace and storing that script in string format, but anyhow thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use regular expression.

```
var javascriptCode="function adding(a,b){ return a+b}"
var regex = /function\s*([^\(]*)\(/
var matchResult = javascriptCode.match(regex)
var funcName = null;
if (matchResult && matchResult.length) {
    funcName = matchResult[1];
}
console.log(funcName);
```

Comment: This is an awesome solution. Thank you.:)

Comment: Side notes: in a future if you are not sure if you have an answer please post comment instead. (I removed questions from your post).

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
var javascriptCode="function adding(a,b){ return a+b}";
var indexStart=javascriptCode.indexOf(" ");
var indexEnd=javascriptCode.indexOf("(");
var res = javascriptCode.substring(indexStart+1, indexEnd);
console.log(res);
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/g6t247w7/1/)**

Comment: Thanks Anik, this one i take it as scond priority :)